# OnLongClickListener blocks OnItemClickListener event

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I'm working on a GUI and I'm currently building a custom ListView. I want to show a pop up menu on a Long click on one of the rows and get the data on a simple click. Everything works fine until i add the OnLongClickListener to the row (i would prefer it if the row could handle this event on its own) i stop getting events to the OnItemClickListener. Any ideas of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `setOnItemLongClickListener` instead on `onLongClickListener`

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener (new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //do your stuff here
  }
});
```

Comment: But then i have to handle the event one level up in the hierarchy. Is it impossible to handle this in the row itself?

Comment: @SverkerSbrg Nope it is not possible to use it in the adapter. why do you want to handle it in the adapter. Let me take a look at your code, post your code

Comment: Ok, then i'll just put it a level up, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See link

[android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

**Returns**
true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise.

Comment: Setting it to false did oddly enough stop the code in the LongClick method from working